# Model without graphics

Tags: graphics, equation-solving, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I have the next code:

`sirds[[Alpha], [Beta], [Delta], [Mu]] := {S[t], SS[t], I[t], R[t],
    D[t]} /.
  First@NDSolve[{
     S'[t] == -[Alpha]*S[t]*I[t] - [Delta]*SS[t],
     I'[t] == [Alpha]*S[t]*I[t] - [Beta]*I[t] - [Mu]*I[t],
     R'[t] == [Beta]*I[t],
     SS'[t] = [Delta]*SS[t],
     D'[t] == [Mu]*I[t], S[0] == 911000, I[0] == 22894, R[0] = 0, 
     D[0] == 196, 
     SS[0] = 0}, {[Alpha], [Beta], [Delta], [Mu]}, {t, 365}]
Manipulate[Plot[
  Evaluate[sirds[[Alpha], [Beta], [Delta], [Mu]]],
  {t, 0, 36},
  PlotLegends -> {"Susceptible", "Vacunada", "Infectada", 
    "Recuperada", "Muerta"},
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 50000},
  PlotStyle -> {
    {Blue, Thickness[0.005]},
    {Red, Thickness[0.005]},
    {Green, Thickness[0.005]},
    {Black, Thickness[0.005]},
    {Yellow, Thickness[0.005]}}],
 {{[Alpha], .017428, "Infectividad"}, 0, .2},
 {{[Beta], .3, "Recuperación"}, 0, .8},
 {{[Delta], .0213577, "Letalidad"}, 0, .2},
 {{[Mu], .002, "Eficacia"}, 0, .2}]`

When I run it, it makes the table that I want, but it doesn't show the graphics that should show. Someone can help me? I took the same structure of this original code that runs perfectly:

`sir[A_, B_, P_ ] := {a[t], f[t], r[t], d[t]} /.
  First@NDSolve[{
     a'[t] == -Aa[t] f[t],
     r'[t] == Bf[t],
     d'[t] == Pf[t],
     f'[t] == Aa[t] f[t] - Bf[t] - Pf[t],
     a[0] == 478530 - 36, f[0] == 36, r[0] == 0, d[0] == 0}, {a, f, r,
      d}, {t, 112}]
Manipulate[Plot[
  Evaluate[sir[A, B, P]],
  {t, 0, 112},
  PlotLegends -> {"Susceptible", "Infectada", "Recuperada", "Muerta"},
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 478530}, PlotStyle -> {
    {Blue, Thickness[0.005]},
    {Red, Thickness[0.005]},
    {Green, Thickness[0.005]},
    {Black, Thickness[0.005]}}],
 {{A, .00000246, "Infectividad"}, 0, 2},
 {{B, .69, "Recuperación"}, 0, 2},
 {{P, .0111, "Letalidad"}, 0, 2}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a very large number of syntax errors. The most serious relate to use of protected symbols: `D`, `I`.

This is a correction that should work. Please adjust plot range to your needs:

```
sirds[α_, β_, δ_, μ_] := {S[t], SS[t], i[t], 
   R[t], d[t]} /. 
  First@NDSolve[{S'[t] == -α*S[t]*i[t] - δ*SS[t], 
     i'[t] == α*S[t]*i[t] - β*i[t] - μ*i[t], 
     R'[t] == β*i[t], SS'[t] == δ*SS[t], 
     d'[t] == μ*i[t], S[0] == 911000, i[0] == 22894, R[0] == 0, 
     d[0] == 196, SS[0] == 0}, {S[t], SS[t], i[t], R[t], d[t]}, {t, 0,
      365}]
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[sirds[α, β, δ, μ]], {t, 0, 36},
   PlotLegends -> {"Susceptible", "Vacunada", "Infectada", 
    "Recuperada", "Muerta"}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 50000}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, {Red, 
     Thickness[0.005]}, {Green, Thickness[0.005]}, {Black, 
     Thickness[0.005]}, {Yellow, 
     Thickness[0.005]}}], {{α, .017428, "Infectividad"}, 
  0, .2}, {{β, .3, "Recuperación"}, 
  0, .8}, {{δ, .0213577, "Letalidad"}, 
  0, .2}, {{μ, .002, "Eficacia"}, 0, .2}]
```